# How to let \part stay solo page and no page number

Tags: page-numbering, parts

My docment class is `book`. The default setting make `\part` stay on a single page but with page number. How to remove the page number?

If I want to customize the part? How to do? Is the `titlesec` package helpful?

Comment: Clearly not a duplicate. This questions asks how to remove the page number, whereas the other question asks how to add it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without any package you can do this be redefining the relevant code for the `\part` command in the preamble of your document.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%   % Original »plain« replaced by »emptyx
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \part{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Might also be done by patching  the `\part` command with the »[etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)« package

Comment: With \patchcmd from etoolbox, you can use `\patchcmd{\part}{\vfil}{\vfil\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}`