# Combine the no page number command with titleformat

Tags: page-numbering, titlesec

My docment class is `book` . I wanted to remove the page number and I was successfull using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54115/how-to-let-part-stay-solo-page-and-no-page-number) command:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%   % Original »plain« replaced by »emptyx
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \part{Foo}
\end{document}
```

In addition I would like to change the format of `part` using `title-sec` package:

```
\titleformat{\part}[display]
      {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\partname\ \thepart}{20pt}{\Large}
\titlespacing*{\part}
      {0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
```

Is there a way to combine both commands?

Comment: Welcome  to TeX SX! Isn't it the default to have no page number on part pages?

Comment: No, it isn't. It is the same for me and for this user: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54115/245844

Comment: Just add `\yjispagestyle{empty}` to the first mandatory argument of  `titleformat`, likethis: `\titleformat{\part}[display]
      {\thispagestyle{empty} \normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\partname\ \thepart}{20pt}{\Large}`.

Comment: Thank you, this one did work! It was quite simple ;-)